# USB stick does not mount

Tags: mount, usb-drive

I have a Kingston 32 GB USB stick. For some reason it doesn't mount and I am not sure how to fix it maybe someone can help me? Here are some inputs:

Disks app shows:
[image]
[image]

Gparted app shows:
[image]

```
➜  ~ dmesg
[ 2656.112680] usb 2-3: USB disconnect, device number 2
[ 2662.944223] usb 2-3: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[ 2662.965155] usb 2-3: LPM exit latency is zeroed, disabling LPM.
[ 2662.965665] usb 2-3: New USB device found, idVendor=13fe, idProduct=5100, bcdDevice= 1.10
[ 2662.965671] usb 2-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 2662.965675] usb 2-3: Product: USB DISK 53X            
[ 2662.965678] usb 2-3: Manufacturer: Phison                  
[ 2662.967209] usb-storage 2-3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 2662.967711] scsi host0: usb-storage 2-3:1.0
[ 2663.973236] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     13FE     USB DISK 50X     PMAP PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
[ 2663.973962] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[ 2663.996868] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

```
➜  ~ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/loop0: 161.4 MiB, 169254912 bytes, 330576 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 2.4 MiB, 2555904 bytes, 4992 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 255.6 MiB, 267980800 bytes, 523400 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 2.2 MiB, 2273280 bytes, 4440 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 2.2 MiB, 2273280 bytes, 4440 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 76.1 MiB, 79745024 bytes, 155752 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop6: 97.7 MiB, 102445056 bytes, 200088 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop7: 162.9 MiB, 170778624 bytes, 333552 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 477 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 92D870DE-2B28-4376-96D5-5FCF8AA5684A

Device             Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1      2048    1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2   1050624  560582655 559532032 266.8G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p3 560582656 1000214527 439631872 209.6G Microsoft basic data


Disk /dev/loop8: 276 KiB, 282624 bytes, 552 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop9: 956 KiB, 978944 bytes, 1912 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop10: 54.8 MiB, 57479168 bytes, 112264 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop11: 217.9 MiB, 228478976 bytes, 446248 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop12: 97.8 MiB, 102486016 bytes, 200168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop13: 956 KiB, 978944 bytes, 1912 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop14: 55.3 MiB, 58007552 bytes, 113296 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop15: 2.5 MiB, 2600960 bytes, 5080 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop16: 62.1 MiB, 65105920 bytes, 127160 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop17: 162.7 MiB, 170549248 bytes, 333104 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop18: 55.4 MiB, 58052608 bytes, 113384 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop19: 89.3 MiB, 93679616 bytes, 182968 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop20: 61 MiB, 63942656 bytes, 124888 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop21: 276 KiB, 282624 bytes, 552 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop22: 162.7 MiB, 170598400 bytes, 333200 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Mounting does not work:

```
➜  ~ sudo mount /dev/sda /home/zlv/usbstick
mount: /home/zlv/usbstick: no medium found on /dev/sda.
```

`/mnt` is empty:

```
➜  ~ ls /mnt/    
➜  ~
```

Comment: 1. Your screenshot of gparted shows your SSD, not the USB stick, so it is pretty useless. You can switch the device in the menu on the top right. 2. You generally cannot mount `/dev/sda`, if there is no `/dev/sda1` for example it means your stick is not formatted.

Comment: 1. gparted sees only one device. 2. Can I format just `/dev/sda`?

Comment: You can try formatting it, but if gparted doesn't see it, that doesn't look good.